# Is there any way to run UITests with out launching iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode-ui-testing, gui-testing

I have been trying to find a solution to run UI Tests for iOS projects without launching the iOS Simulator. My intention is to run `xcodebuild` command from Terminal for CI pipeline but without launching the iOS Simulator.

I am using below command to run UI test suite for my iOS project, this works fine but launches the iOS Simulator
`xcodebuild test -project iOSTesting.xcodeproj -scheme 'iOSTestingUITests' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15 Pro' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15'`

I was able to find a solution on GitHub where the UI Tests run without launching the iOS Simulator, but I am not able to find out how it is working, here is the link to the source code.
https://github.com/Shashikant86/Xcode9-XCTest

Any thoughts?

Comment: @matt, thanks, I was testing both Unit tests and UI Tests. But my question is particular to UI Tests. I have updated the question with UI test scheme now. I also saw your other post you shared earlier. I completely agree with your thoughts. But what surprises me is how the GitHub code I shared in the link is able to run UI tests without launching the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the behavior of the project you pointed to by making a new project and running `xcodebuild` on it. Follow these steps to try it:

- Make a new storyboard-based iOS project called MyCoolApp, including tests. Save it on the Desktop.
- Make sure that you have created a Simulator for iPhone 15, OS 17.2. I don't know whether this step is necessary but let's not take any chances.
- Launch the Terminal and `cd Desktop/MyCoolApp`.
- Still in the Terminal, give this command, which is essentially the command that you provided:

  ```
  xcodebuild -project MyCoolApp.xcodeproj -scheme "MyCoolApp" -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15,OS=17.2' build test CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
  ```

The tests run but at no time does the Simulator app appear on the screen.

Comment: I followed your steps using Xcode 15.0.1 and tried with iOS 17.0, but I still see the Simulator loading for UI tests. I am looking for more of a technical answer why one project is loading the simulator vs not. Because when I search the same query in stackoverflow I see lots of people saying it will launch the simulator. But I am not understanding why your project does not load the simulator? is there a setting/configuration that is preventing it from loading?

Comment: what I observed so far is, I am also able to run UI tests with out launching the Simulator. Here is the behavior. If the iOS Simulator is not already launched it will not launch and complete the tests and if an instance of iOS Simulator is already launched then it will launch the simulator for the tests. I am still trying to validate this behavior.

Comment: Wow, hot stuff. I think what's going to happen here is that you're going to solve the problem, you're going to write your own answer, I'm going to delete my answer, and your answer will be useful to others! That is my Amazing Prediction.